# Sorting files in a folder by the application that created them

Tags: windows-7, sorting

I'd like to have a better idea of why there are certain files in my TEMP folder, so I'm wondering if there's any record kept in Windows 7 about the application that created a particular file.

I looked through the possible grouping options that are visible when you Right-click the white space in a folder > Group by > More.. , but nothing stands out. I was hoping for a choice of "Application" or "Created by" but yeah nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't provide that information. However, if there are any file which is "in use", you can find the related application using a software called "Process Explorer" from Windows SysInternals.